# Regex: Select and delete words that contain less than 3 letters in an particular tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this example:

`<meta name="abstract" content="Moment, lovin, of, superman, | jonny, Deep, is"/>`

I want to delete words like `of,` or `is` from this tag.

The result should be:

`<meta name="abstract" content="Moment, lovin, superman, | jonny, Deep"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<meta name="abstract" content="|\G)[^"]*?\K,\h+(?:is|of)\b`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                                 # non capture group
    <meta name="abstract" content="     # literally
  |                                   # OR
    \G                                  # restart from last match position
)                                   # end group
[^"]*?                              # 0 or more non quote, not greedy
\K                                  # forget all we have seen until this position
,                                   # a comma
\h+                                 # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?:is|of)                           # non capture group, is OR of
\b                                  # word boundary
```

Use `[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b` instead of `(?:is|of)\b` to remove all words of 1 or 2 character long.

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: is ok. But I need something like {3} because there are not the same words like (`is` or `of`)